# calling a function in file1.as from file2.as?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, function, flex4, function-pointers

How can I call a function in file1.as from file2.as?

here is the code.

```
package com.modestmaps
{
        import com.modestmaps.overlays.MarkerClip;

        import flash.display.Graphics;
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.display.Shape;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
        import flash.geom.Matrix;
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        //import mx.core.Application;
        import mx.core.Application;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class InfoBubble extends Sprite
{
    private var btn_close:String = "http://(.yada.yada.)/media/close_button.swf";
    public var textField:TextField;
    public var background:Shape;
    public var shadow:Shape;
    public var infoClip:MarkerClip;

    protected var map:InfoMap;
    //var infoClip:MarkerClip;
    public var infoBubble:InfoBubble;
    public function InfoBubble(urlLink:String)
    {
        //the name of my markers are set to the links of the swf files in which I want to load into the infobubble
        this.name = urlLink;
        this.mouseEnabled = false;
        this.mouseChildren = true;
        this.buttonMode=false;

        shadow = new Shape();
        shadow.filters = [ new BlurFilter(16, 16) ];
        shadow.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, -0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);   
        addChild(shadow);

        background = new Shape();
        addChild(background);

        textField = new TextField();
        textField.selectable = false;
        //the infobubble is still sized according to the textField.width and height
        //I don't know how to get the size of the loaded swf
        textField.width = textField.textWidth+432+4;
        textField.height = textField.textHeight+288+4;

        //add main swf
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlLink);
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(request);
        addChild(loader);

        //position the main swf
        //current measurements of swf file w432 h288
        loader.y = -288 - 37;
        loader.x = mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.LBloaderX;

        //add close button
        var reqButton:URLRequest = new URLRequest(btn_close);
        var loader2:Loader = new Loader();
        loader2.load(reqButton);
        addChild(loader2);

        loader2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeInfoBubble);

        function closeInfoBubble(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        infoClip.removeMarkerObject(infoBubble)
        infoBubble = null
        }
        //position the closebutton swf
        //current measurements of closebutton swf file w18 h18
        loader2.y = -286 - 37;
        loader2.x = mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.LBloader2X;

        // remember that things in marker clips are positioned with (0,0) at the given location
        textField.y = -textField.height - 35;
        textField.x = -10;

        //I need to find out how to detect the width and height of the swf file loaded into loader2
        //instead of the size of the textField
        var rect:Rectangle = textField.getRect(this);

        // get your graph paper ready, here's a "speech bubble"
        background.graphics.beginFill(0x12345);
        shadow.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);

        for each (var g:Graphics in [ background.graphics, shadow.graphics ] ) {
            g.moveTo(rect.left, rect.top);
            g.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top);
            g.lineTo(rect.right, rect.bottom);
            g.lineTo(rect.left+15, rect.bottom);
            g.lineTo(rect.left+10, rect.bottom+15);
            g.lineTo(rect.left+5, rect.bottom);
            g.lineTo(rect.left, rect.bottom);
            g.lineTo(rect.left, rect.top);
            g.endFill();
        } 
    }
    }
}
```

in this package i am attempting to add the shadow, which works, and then add the infobubble, which works, and then add a main swf which works, and then add a close_button.swf which it does load the swf; however, when I try to add the listener, I am unable to make the infobubble close back up.

Comment: A litle more explanation : What are you trying todo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention typically allows for one .as file per class, so you would need to have a reference to an instantiated object of that class inside the second one.

That said, we need -way- more information to provide any kind of useful answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with ModestMaps? If so, I could easily explain, otherwise I will have to throw some code up so you can see. I am new to as3 and flex.

Comment: Haven't used it before, looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Tegeril's answer:  Aside from accessing the functions inside of an instantiated class, you could also (as is the case in a utility class), make the functions static.  In this case you could call the method like so:  ClassName.methodName(), without the need to instantiate.... my random 2p.

Comment: could you expand on this possibly over messenger?